# Counting file with linux command

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I am a new linux user. I am trying to count all of file files in the home(~) directory. So did it in the following steps -

1. `ls -1 > fileCount # list each file in separate line and places them in fileCount`
2. `wc -l  fileCount # word count from the file fileCount`

The procedure above gives me the correct file count. But it is a bit lengthy process and require a file to be generated.

Is there any better way to count all the file  from the current directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thaks a lot it works for me. Could you explain a bit what is done by the `|` operator and name of the operator? I didn't know it.

Comment: Pipes let you use the output of a program as the input of another one. Here you can find a couple of additional examples. 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html
Pipes are a very power tool to do a lot of things if the *nix world :P